# How to search after input value that must be between two feature values in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, layered-navigation

To understand it fully I will give a clear example:

Our webshop sells zip ties. Every zip ties can be tightened between a minimum and a maximum diameter. For example say from 0.5" to 2".
In most of the cases the buyer needs a zip tie for a specific needed diameter. What we need is to have a possibility to get an input for the needed diameter and list all the zip ties where this input is between the minimum and maximum diameter.

I have tried different variations with layered navigation but it can not be done with it.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: have you tried the slider thing in bloclayered?

Comment: Hi Julien, yes I have tried different things with that too. THe slider is a different version of a dropdown, nothing else. You can select between existing values from one feature. What I need is that the user inputs a value (i.e 1" as needed diameter) and it lists all the products where minimum diameter < 1" < maximum diameter.

Comment: Erven you should open blocklayered and check how it works with price. Its same - slider thing. Bot you must add additional functions.

Comment: elPresta, thanks. I have thought about that but thats just the opposite what I need. For price it asks for minimum and maximum (2 different) inputs and lists those products where price is between the two selected. 
In my case I have one single input and need to search between 2 features: minimum and maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize blocklayered module, some tips:

let's imagine in shop each product have 2 different features "min diameter" and "max diameter" and you already created filter for them, checkboxes.

- hide these blocks by *display:none*
- add in template input field for the actual diameter value.
- after customer's input, select all min/max checkboxes that satisfy the condition
- call blocklayered method to send the filters.

Comment: Now that sounds genious!!! I'm going to try it and be back with feedback. Thanks Sergii P! It really sounds like a perfect solution.

Comment: @Ervin I glad to hear it :)